# Web Sharing (Apache) won't turn on in Lion

Tags: macos, apache, webserver

I'm unable to enable web sharing via `System Preferences > Sharing`.  When I click it to turn it on the light turns yellow but then goes back to gray.

I did some Googling and found that many people solved this problem by removing changes in their `httpd.conf`.  This is my `ls /etc/apache2/*.conf*`:

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
/etc/apache2/httpd_ACSServer.conf
/etc/apache2/httpd_devicemanagement.conf
/etc/apache2/httpd_podcastlibrary.conf
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf.default
```

I tried replacing `httpd.conf` with `httpd.conf.default` but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: /var/log/apache2/error_log should contain more details on problems Apache encounters when failing to start.

Comment: Try `sudo apachectl start` on the command line. See if that works. If that doesn't work `sudo apachectl configtest` will display the errors in your config files…

Answer (score 2):

Check the Apache logs with Applications > Utilities > Console. Inside Console, expand `/var/log` to see the Apache2 log files. You might see a message in error_log.

Without any messages, it is a wild goose chase. Here, last time Apache did not log any messages it was the port 80 being occupied by another process.

Comment: This worked for me, helped me to track down a failing passenger install after moving from rvm to rbenv. Totally forgot I had set that up local for apache.