# Web Sharing not getting enabled in MAC OSX10.7.4

Tags: macos, apache, web-sharing

I have tried enabling *Web Sharing* in MAC OSX 10.7.4, but after clicking to check it uncheck it self. I know there's a similar question for it, that is, [Web Sharing (Apache) won't turn on in Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65092/web-sharing-apache-wont-turn-on-in-lion).

Here is crash log that I get in "/var/log/apache2/error_log" file:

```
[Wed Mar 13 17:46:52 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Mar 13 17:46:52 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Mar 13 17:46:52 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Mar 13 17:49:51 2013] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /usr/htdocs
[Wed Mar 13 17:52:20 2013] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /usr/htdocs
[Wed Mar 13 17:52:59 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Arpit.local for ServerName
[Mon Mar 18 18:23:03 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Mar 18 18:23:03 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Mar 18 18:23:03 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Mar 18 18:23:05 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Arpit.local for ServerName
No log handling enabled - using stderr logging
Created directory: /var/db/net-snmp
Created directory: /var/db/net-snmp/mib_indexes
[Wed May 01 16:36:04 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed May 01 16:36:04 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed May 01 16:36:04 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.10 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 01 16:43:26 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Arpit.local for ServerName
[Wed May 01 16:43:26 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed May 01 16:43:26 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed May 01 16:43:26 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.10 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 01 17:24:26 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

I tried looking into it but couldn't get exact reason.

Comment: The symptoms (WebSharing not staying enabled) may be the same, the cause might not. So let's keep the questions separate for now.

Comment: +1 but, If i had authority to edit your comment I would have edited it like, the problem may be same but symptoms might not. So.......... :)